# Array function pointer referencing a function using a mulidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am a beginner in c programming.  I am trying to reference the following functions in an array function pointer as shown in processGrades 4 element array.  I am having trouble getting the grades array 3 x 4 to pass through to the functions.  I am trying to use pointers but I do not seem to be formating the pointer properly.  I would appreciate help or a reference to help understand how to do this.  My reference is very basic.

```
void minimum(int grades[][EXAMS], size_t pupils, size_t tests);
void maximum(int grades[][EXAMS], size_t pupils, size_t tests);
void average(int grades[][EXAMS], size_t pupils, size_t tests);
void printArray(int grades[][EXAMS], size_t pupils, size_t tests);

void(*processGrades[4])(int, size_t, size_t) = { printArray, minimum, maximum, average };
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument type of the pointer is incorrect. You should change `int` to `int[][EXAMS]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
typedef void (*processGrades)(int[][MAX], size_t, size_t);
```